# Backslash does not escape double quotes

Tags: javascript, string

The following string shows double quotes and backslsh when runs:

```
"<img src=\"abc/xyz/"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: please add more details, in which context shows double quotes?

Comment: What's the full HTML?

Comment: _"The following string shows double quotes when runs:"_ What is expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are using it, but a simple solution use single quotes on outside and remove backslash.

```
'<img src="abc/xyz" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full string, it isn't complete. There's no closing quote `"` nor `>` bracket

This would be a valid `<img>` element string

```
"<img src=\"abc/xyz/\">"
```